# Compare routes in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, navigation, routes

I'm trying to create a algorithm to define a 'standard' route and afterwards compare that route with all future routs that a person is going to take. The start- and end-point is the same, so it's basically a circle.

I already have an Android app that sends a location to my server every 10 seconds. I need to create a route out of those points, and then in the first week i need to create an avarage route between the routs taken in that week. That inners of that road (the area within the 'circle') have to be marked as a safe zone and i need to get a warning whenever i get a location from outside that zone.

So my question remains; how can I make this possible? Where should I start looking and is there already some API that could help me?

I know that my case is very bad written, but if you have question please don't hesitate..

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hey Galip did you get any solution for this problem I have a similar problem here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641931/how-to-compare-two-routes-using-google-direction-apis-or-some-other-apis-for-iph    can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could save each route using the DirectionsService.  No idea how you then determine an 'average' out of that though.  But once you have that average route determined, you could calculate the bounds around the entire route (or more likely you want to work out a polygon either side of the route) and then you can check if a point is outwith that area.